# Issue importing .osm file with blender-osm add-on

Tags: add-on

I'm having trouble importing Open Streetmap Files.  When I do, I get this error:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

and it shows an empty:

[image]

I'm currently using blender-osm add-on but after reading the installation instructions I can't figure out what's going on.  I've used a number of .osm files (manually selected as well as general areas like a whole city) and it produces the same result every time.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: That's not the entire error message. Please copy all of it in your question, including the stack trace. Also include which version of Blender you're using, and on which OS.

Comment: @dr.Sybren  That's all I see for the error...is there a way to get a stack trace in Windows? I wasn't able to find a method online for that. I'm using Windows 10, Blender version 2.79.

Comment: Please contact the addon developer using of the ways listed [here](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/wiki/Documentation#links-and-contacts)